# Cannot start project in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm pretty new to Rails.

I created a new Rails app: `rails new app_name`, and ran `rails server` etc.

But, once I shut down and reopened my machine, I can run neither `rails server` nor `rails console`. It says to use the `rails new app_name` command again, but I just want to restart where I left off the day before.

Any advice is very much appreciated.

Comment: try pasting your complete error code that you are getting on your console, it might help people to tell what the actual problem is, also check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask to get started

Comment: Are you in the correct directory (i.e. the directory of the app you created)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your current working directory of your command line is not in your project directory which you created yesterday.

```
cd some_path/to_my/rails_project
rails server
```

You must be in the directory that represents your project to do things like launch the server. Otherwise, how does it know what project to launch a server for?

Comment: Actually I wasn't in my projects directory. OOPS. Thanks

Comment: @MaximBashminov Glad to have helped you. But when your question is answered on Stack Overflow, you need to accept the answer that worked for you by clicking the checkmark button by the helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you are in the directory of the rails app you created.  Sounds like you aren't.